# Android: 9-patch png is treated like a normal png

Tags: android, android-layout, background, png, nine-patch

I've made this 9-patch png and added it to the res/drawable folder:

[image]

It works nice in the example eclipse shows:

[image]

But on the emulator it looks messed up:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

EDIT: The border on which I've placed the black dots is white, not transparent. Not sure if that's got anything to do with it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably happens because you have a small mistake with the black pixels you have set.
Try to re-cut the edges of the picture and to add the black pixels all over again.

I had this problem too once and this helped me.

if the border is white then this is your problem it has to be pure black or nothing at all.

**UPDATE:** Try this image:

[image]

Comment: if the border is white then this is your problem it has to be pure black or nothing at all.

Comment: I re-added the black pixel, but still the same problem. It's pure black 0 red, 0 blue 0 green.

Comment: and what about the white border?

Comment: Does the border have to be transparent or is white okay?

Comment: I made the white border transparent, but it didn't work. Now things are getting really weird. The picture is scaled properly, but the other views are being pushed to the upper left corner, covering about 1/4 of the screen. These 9-patches are driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are not saved your image with .9.png

In order to make it work do like this 
save your image in the following format in your drawable folder

`yourimage.9.png` (not png format of your image)

Check this reference [draw 9 patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Comment: @Merlin Then change your border to black instead of white

Answer (score 2):

The Android SDK contains a 9-patch editing tool (draw9patch.bat) that can help you to produce and/or validate 9-patch images.  Without it, it is very easy to make a mistake in defining your border.

The one-pixel border should be transparent except for the black pixels that define the various parts of the image to be treated differently during scaling.

Comment: Yeah, I used that tool. I don't really like it though, but at least it works. Thanks for your clearification!

Comment: It's a bit klunky but I've found it to be helpful at times.